# Why does splitting with RegEx group include the group in the result?

Tags: javascript, regex

I don't understand this.

```
> 'a\nb'.split(/\n/)       
[ 'a', 'b' ]               
> 'a\nb'.split(/(\n)/)     
[ 'a', '\n', 'b' ]
```

Why?

Comment: haha, downvote is understandable. well... I think it still is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting MDN Documentation on [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Description),

> If **separator** is a regular expression that contains capturing parentheses, then each time separator is matched, the results (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output array.

Quoting [ECMAScript 5.1 Standard Specification for `String.prototype.split`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.5.4.14),

> If *separator* is a regular expression that contains capturing parentheses, then each time *separator* is matched the results (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output array. For example,
>
> ```
> "A<B>bold</B>and<CODE>coded</CODE>".split(/<(\/)?([^<>]+)>/)
> ```
>
> evaluates to the array
>
> ```
> ["A", undefined, "B", "bold", "/", "B", "and", undefined, "CODE", "coded", "/", "CODE", ""]
> ```

So the `split` is working as expected only.

Comment: @StevenLu You already know that capturing groups are not necessary in this case, so why non-capturing group is needed as a solution here? :-)

Comment: well the question was an oversimplification... basically i expected never to see something out of the delimiter itself in the result array, so the way to minimally change a regex that perhaps requires a group to have it no longer include the group in the split result is to make it a noncapturing group.

Comment: Oh yeah. In that case non-capturing groups would work.

Comment: Indeed, I tried earlier but it was 7 minutes before I was allowed to accept it.